# findall() in yii return array and i want it to return object how

Tags: yii

i have w function called update that i want to update a specific record in database according to module id (m_id) and key (key)

here is the function

```
public function updateRecord($module,$key,$newData){

    $id = $this->module($module);
    $model = new Form;
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->condition = "`m_id` = 1 AND `key` = 'txt'";
    // $model = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT * FROM `tbl_setting` WHERE `m_id` = 1 AND `key` = 'txt'")->query();

    die(var_dump($model->findAll($criteria)));
    // $model = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT * FROM `tbl_setting` WHERE `m_id` = 1 AND `key` = 'txt'")->execute();



    $model->m_id = $id ;
    $model->attributes = $newData;
    $model->save();
    //die(print_r($model['m_id']));
    //if(isset($_POST['save'])){
        //$model['m_id'] = $id;

    //}
}
```

every time i try to use this function it give me error that $model is not an object so it can't execute

```
$model->m_id = $id ;
```

i check out the type of findAll() and it gives an array

i checkout all find() methods and only findByPk() that give an object

and i want to choose  according to the $criteria and i don't know what to do any help ?! :)

Comment: Your question is unclear. You have to add more code and give more explanation about your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findAll` will always return an array. With objects if there are record found, or an empty array on no result. `find` only returns 1 record, or NULL if nothing is found:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#find-detail

Your code will be save when you do it like this:

```
if(!is_null($model)) {
    $model->m_id = $id ;
    $model->attributes = $newData;
    $model->save();
} else {
    echo 'No record found';
}
```